# Mathematical permutation drawing/visualization tool

Tags: permutations, visualization

I'm writing software and need to document an existing mathematical permutation in our code.

I thought the folks here would know where I can find a drawing/visualization tool to draw a permutation tree.

```
$a     $b        $c
true   true      true    134
true   true      false   245
true   false     true    2
true   false     false   3
false  true      true    8
false  true      false   17
false  false     true    19
false  false     false   32
```

Comment: What's a permutation tree?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, Edited to show example.

Comment: I think this might be what mostly is called a "decision tree".  It might be a better question for programmers/SE since no math or software development is involved.

Answer (score 2):

[This website](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/trees/) lists several LaTeX packages for drawing trees.  While it seems more geared towards linguists who are making parse trees, I am sure that most of the packages are flexible enough to do what you need.  Moreover, there are more generic drawing packages such as TikZ or pstricks that, while not specifically designed for making trees, should work quite well.

Comment: In fact TikZ has dedicated libraries to drawing beautiful trees.